# EmberJS, WebStorm and Windows - Cannot run through Ember Serve configuration

Tags: ember.js, webstorm

I've created an ember-quickstart application from `ember-cli` and it loads successfully in my browser with `ember serve`. I've imported the project into WebStorm and tried to set up a configuration under option Ember Serve like so:

[image]

However, when I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
C:/DEV/nvm/v10.16.0/node C:/DEV/Projects/ember-quickstart/node_modules/.bin/ember serve
C:\DEV\Projects\ember-quickstart\node_modules\.bin\ember:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to run the server from the command line each time?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with [Ember](https://github.com/Turbo87/intellij-emberjs) plugin - it tries to start ember with `node path/to/node_modules/.bin/ember serve`, but `.bin/ember` is a linux/unix shell script and not a JavaScript file - thus the error. I'd suggest filing an issue to https://github.com/Turbo87/intellij-emberjs/issues/.

As a workaround, you can try the following:

- start Ember by opening your `package.json` in editor and clicking the *run* icon the the gutter to the left of `start` script:

[image]

this will create **NPM** run configuration you can re-use later

- create a **JavaScript Debug** run configuration like:

[image]

- press **Debug**